# Can I get a chars_ptr from an Unbounded_String with minimal copying?

Tags: c, string, ada

I have an `Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String`, which I'd like to pass to a C function which takes a `char *` (`Interfaces.C.chars_ptr` in Ada).

My current implementation involves copying the unbounded string to a fixed string, then copying the fixed string to a `chars_ptr`.

```
F_String : String := To_String (UB_String);
C_String : chars_ptr := New_String (F_String);
```

Notice that this copies twice, when all in the end I would just be calling

```
Imported_Function (C_String);
Free (C_String);
```

And discarding `F_String`.

Can I achieve the desired behaviour (passing the string held in an Unbounded String to an imported C function) using minimal copying? Ideally it would be cool to pass the internal buffer of  `UB_String` straight to the function, but this probably wouldn't be portable. Can I at least achieve the same behaviour without needing the intermediate fixed string?

I saw that GNAT has the internal package `Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Aux` which allows you to get an access to the internal buffer of the Unbounded String, but this isn't portable and could potentially break between versions of GNAT.

Comment: Note that there is no requirement that an Unbounded_String be implemented with all the characters in sequence in memory.  (One can imagine an implementation where a large Unbounded_String is stored in chunks of <= N characters where the chunks are in a linked list.  I've written text-handling stuff like that in the past; there are advantages and disadvantages.)  So there's no general portable solution.  For your particular problem, you may be best off writing your own unbounded string type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String manipulation in ada is a pain and there is not much you can do besides avoid using unbounded strings in the first place (maybe only use them when you need a string field in a record?).

```
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;
...
procedure Imported_Function(Item : in access Interfaces.C.Char);
pragma Import(C, Imported_Function, "...");
Item : aliased Interfaces.C.Char_Array := To_C(To_String(UB_String)); -- no need to free
begin
  Imported_Function(Item(Item'first)'access);
  ...
```

Comment: There's no need to use access here. Arrays are passed as t* to C anyway. See [RM B.3/70](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-3.html)

Comment: Good point, I didn't even know that : ).

It does work either way though and is a little more explicit. I think it comes down to a style choice.

Answer (score 1):

The short and disappointing answer is: Not in a portable way.

But you have some options available:

1. Drop the portability and hook into the internals of the specific version of the standard library coming with your compiler.
2. Write your own string type, which lives up to your requirements.
3. Accept the extra copy until you can see that it is a problem for your application.

Ad. 1:

It seems like you have found out how to hook into the GNAT Ada.Strings.Unbounded package.

Ad. 2:

Consider *how* "unbounded" your string type really has to be.  Do you know an almost certain upper bound on the length?  Would it be unreasonable to allocate twice as many VM pages per string as you actually need in the worst known case?  What is an acceptable action in case you haven't allocated enough memory?  Failing?  Allocating more and copying?  Creating a linked list and then having to make a copy for "export" purposes?  It is not all that difficult to create custom types in Ada, so consider that, if you have some special requirements (as it sounds like in this case).